# Software or workarounds for vector autoregression on count data?

Tags: poisson-distribution, count-data, vector-autoregression

I have a research question that fits nicely in a VAR framework but my data are count data. They are much closer to a Poisson or negative binomial distribution than they are to a normal.

This will bias the estimates and errors of the VAR (though I'm not sure in which direction).

Does anybody know of any packages or programs I can use to estimate a Poisson or Neg. Binomial VAR?

If not, is there a recommended work around?

Comment: Since a VAR model can be estimated consistently (although generally not efficiently) by estimating each equation separately, you could perhaps consider what you would do if you had just one equation of a VAR model. If you find a solution for this simpler problem, you could perhaps just do the whole thing equation by equation. And you could post your solution as a new question to get comments and critique.

Answer (score 1):

There is a A Bayesian Poisson Vector Autoregression Model proposed by Brandt and Sandler. You can see a copy of there manuscript here [1](http://www.utdallas.edu/~tms063000/website/BaPVAR-20111230.pdf). The manuscript also contains a good literature review of prior versions of VARs for count variables.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, this isn't very difficult, basically the same as what you do with GLMs. You can have a vector autoregression in a latent Gaussian space which parameterize a count distribution.  This is somewhat different from Brant and Sandler's approach which doesn't have a covariance matrix at all. We can think about the pros and cons of these approach.  Over on the Stan Forums I shared code that seems to work with a Poisson model [1](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/poisson-vector-autoregression-model/3462/7?u=groceryheist).

I'm trying to make it work with a negative binomial link, but sampling is more difficult.